# fixed number recurssion set in php

Tags: php

I have a fixed number recursion set with me. I need to get a random variable and get the left and right values and store them in an array. In the for loop i need to increment the array index...how do i go about it....if the uid is set to 1 it works perfect but in case of any other number i cannnot just get the logic....

the code is like this

```
// global id
$uid=3; // Take from session.

// Range Array
$range[0]=$uid;
$range[1]=2;  // level 0
$range[2]=4;  // level 1
$range[3]=8;    // level 2
$range[4]=16;   // level 3
$range[5]=32;   // level 4
$range[6]=64;   // level 5
$range[7]=128;  // level 6
$range[8]=256;  // level 7
$range[9]=512;  // level 8
$range[10]=1024;    // level 9
$range[11]=2048;    // level 10
// Range array ends.

$gar[0]=$uid;



$leftid=$uid*2;
$rightid=($uid*2)+1;


// Generate Levels

//Level 1. 2 Elements

    $gar[1]=$leftid;
    $gar[2]=$rightid;


// Level 2. 4 elements

    // range starts with element 1 of range array.
        $i=($gar[1]*2);
        $ip=($i+$range[2])-1;
        $ak=3;
        for($x=$i; $x<=$ip; $x++)   
                {
                 $gar[$x-1]=$x;
                }
            var_dump($gar);
```

The output is as follows if uid is set to 3. If you see the array key has not incremented..

```
array (size=7)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 6
  2 => int 7
  11 => int 12
  12 => int 13
  13 => int 14
  14 => int 15
```

Comment: Can you show the output you expect for, let's say `$uid = 3`?

Comment: yes if the uid is 3 then the output will be
6 as $gar[1] and 7 as $gar[2]...

Comment: Current output is 
    array (size=7)
      0 => int 3
      1 => int 6
      2 => int 7
      11 => int 12
      12 => int 13
      13 => int 14
      14 => int 15

Comment: I meant the output you want it to be; not the output it is currently generating. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i got it instead of using what i was duoing i used array push to increment it....thanx hjpotter92